# Conditionally add JSF components into translation string

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have this String

```
The [inputText 1] is using for [inputText 2] days
```

both `inputText` are JSF component `h:inputText` that have `validator`, `onfocus`, `value` ...

The issue is translation. So let say, I want to translate the above string, it would do something like this

```
#{ifn:translate('The')}
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.val1}" validator="#{myBean.validator1}" />
#{ifn:translate('is.using.for')}
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.val2}" validator="#{myBean.validator2}" />
#{ifn:translate('days')}
```

However, these does not work well with let say Japanese translation. First, in Japanese, there is no `The`. Second, the positions of the `inputText` are only make sense for English, but for Japanese, the `inputText` need to be some other locations. One solution I see is to embed the html component in the translation string in `.properties` file, like this

label_en.properties

```
my.String=The <input >{0}</input> is using for <input >{1}</input> days
```

label_jp.properties

```
my.String=<input >{0}</input> XXX XXX XXX <input >{1}</input> XXX XXX XXX
```

However, this solution wont work for JSF component like `h:inputText`, so can anyone suggest another solution for this. Thank you

Comment: why dont you use 'render' attribute on <h:inputText> tag to conditionally render it ?

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya: I think you mis-understand. Please re-read the post. The problem is the difference in grammar and sentence structure between different language. Correct solution is what `LaurentG` posted below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it with JSF only (beside creating your own component).

I would use [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) in this case to solve the problem:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{label['my.String']}" escape="false">
    <o:param><h:inputText value="#{myBean.val1}" validator="#{myBean.validator1}" /></o:param>
    <o:param><h:inputText value="#{myBean.val2}" validator="#{myBean.validator2}" /></o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

label_en.properties:

```
my.String = The {0} is using for {1} days
```